# Travel within Schengen Area with Fiktionbescheinigung and within 90 day allowance

Tags: schengen

I have received a 81, 3.1 Fiktionsbescheinigung (which I know does not normally allow you to re-enter Germany). I have 34 days left on my visa-free travel in the EU as a British citizen and I want to go to France via train/bus for a weekend. Would this be permitted as I still have 34 days left or can you not travel at all with this type of Fiktionsbescheinigung?

Answer (score 3):

As a a British citizen, you can travel to France (or to any other Schengen couuntry) as long as you are within your otherwise 90 days allowance. The fictional certificate does not reduce your right to travel.

You should however be aware that if you exceed a stay of 90 days, a fictional certificate issued based on 81, 3.1 does only allow you to remain in Germany. You are not allowed to travel to other Schengen countries, not even in transit if you are on your way to leave the Schengen area, and you are not allowed to reenter Germany if you leave.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Does this go for re-entering Germany too. That there would not be a problem as long as I am in my 90 days?

Comment: @LaurenJames As I already wrote: "The fictional certificate does not reduce your right to travel." I am not sure how I can explain it more clearly. If you are allowed to enter Germany without the fictional certificate, you will also be allowed to enter with the fictional certificate.